# Pygtk Image Loading too slow / load smaller

Tags: python, pygtk

I am writing a file browser using pygtk. For image files I am showing some previews by loading images by pixbuf_new_from_file and scaling them. In directories with large files (like when browsing a portfolio) it takes too long. Is it possible to load the images with lower resolution?

Whole code can be found on [Git](https://github.com/arkocal/filebrowser). In dirFrame.py the function renderMainDirContent is the part that takes too long.

pixbuf_new_from_file_at_size seems to load full image and scale, as it has almost no effect on performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is no faster way to do this with python. Using numpy to load and scale images improves performance, but you need to save thumbnails for acceptable performance, at least for large images.